# Should the unofficial "1 Day Rule" become an suggestion?

Tags: feature-request

I think that the "1 day rule" - a unofficial guideline where a user should wait at least a day before accepting an answer - should be an actual suggestion, and not just "unofficial".

This could be done in two ways I can think of:

### 1. Help Center / Tutorial Page

New users are the ones to most likely accept an answer prematurely. It would work by adding a suggestion in the help center or tutorial: "*it is helpful to accept an answer a day after posting because it allows for multiple users (from all time zones) to answer and may provide insights that otherwise might've been lost*".

### 2. A Popup

If an user clicks the accept as answer button, it could popup a message asking for confirmation. There should be a "never show this again" checkbox, though. Something simple like this would work:

```
acceptButton.addEventListener('click',confirmAccept);
function confirmAccept(){
now = new Date();
if(now.getTime() - postCreationDate.getTime < 24*60*60*100){
acceptPopup.style.display = 'block'
acceptPopup.style.opacity = '0';
acceptAnimation = acceptPopup.animate([{opacity: 0, opacity: 1}],
        { duration: 600, iterations: 1, fill: "forwards" })
acceptAnimation.addEventListener("finish", ()=>{
acceptPopup.style.opacity = '1';
})
}
}
function acceptPopupHide(){
acceptPopup.style.opacity = '1';
acceptAnimation = acceptPopup.animate([{opacity: 1, opacity: 0}],
        { duration: 600, iterations: 1, fill: "forwards" })
acceptAnimation.addEventListener("finish", ()=>{
acceptPopup.style.opacity = '0';
acceptPopup.style.display = 'none';
})
}
acceptPopupConfirm.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
acceptAnswer();
acceptPopupHide();
})
acceptPopupCancel.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
acceptPopupHide();
})
```

Comment: Two days is better, but I'd settle for one!

Comment: I like the idea of making this "suggestion" more visible but suspect you'll need to take your idea to [official Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Do we have enough control at Worldbuilding to change how buttons work? (I think it might be a site level change request?)

Answer (score 3):

### I agree with your proposal

I don't recall how many times I went "too late" to a question because, well, I was just sleeping. Well, it's part because I have the memory of a goldfish struck by Alzeihmer , but I'm almost certain it's also because it happened quite a lot.

I don't know the exact text which should be written down, but here's what I can tell regarding a change in the help-center :

- It should be kept short : 1 sentence or two max.
- This place should be the best one to put this advice in : [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Do note however that not many people go this far into the help-center, and people are less enticed to follow advices than strict rules. So the impact this change will have is not likely be very strong.

### Proposal #2 will have to go through meta first

That's the ideal proposal, with a very strong effect. However, I doubt users nor moderators on this meta can do much about this. You'll have to post it on [SE's über-meta-site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). It's the one where global changes are talked about, including website code and visuals.

I can't know how the proposal will end up there. However, here's one or two tips to improve its chances of succeding :

- Please don't demonstrate with code. Code is boring in every marketing pitch and not everyone are computer gods of the matrix .

  - Instead, use a screenshot displaying the use case. It doesn't need to be pretty, just to show when it happens (cursor on the "accept" button) and what happens (a popup saying "Heya! Wait one single day, pretty please?").
- Explain more clearly the circumstances of the trigger and its effects. Here are some questions you should answer to help out :

  - Does this popup appear to every user, or only new ones?
  - Is it triggered only once per site, or an undefinite number of times?
  - Are there other circumstances you are seeing it used/not used (once per day to not spam very active querents, retriggerable after a long inactivity...).

Comment: Thanks! I'll go to meta and post it there instead. Have a nice day!

Answer (score -4):

I disagree.

Why?

Because Answers are subjective to the answerer. Imagine a question where there are multiple 'good' answers (by community standards) but the person who reads the answers looks at them in the wider context of their story/World and one answer just 'clicks' - whether it's because it's something they just completely overlooked or because it has ramifications for other parts of the world/story that we don't know about (but they do) or they just have a vibe for that answer - why should we place an arbitrary limit on them delaying accepting the answer?

In addition, I don't think the asker is prevented from changing their mind and selecting another question as the answer at a later date.

Comment: Would you be fine if your answer that was accepted is suddenly changed for another? Beyond removing the trophy from someone's hands, changes -especially when they are frequent- can hint that the querent has troubles deciding what they want, or worse that they don't know at all which answer is best for them (opinion-based/lacks clarity closures).

Comment: Point is, like answerers are not forced to answer right now, nothing actually changes for the querent to wait. It's not like their opinion will change tomorrow when one answer "clicked" but didn't get accepted right away .

Comment: @Tortliena - I'm not a fan of arbitrary rules in general. I can think of a few questions I've answered where it was accepted very quickly and the querent posted a comment like 'I can't believe I didn't think of that - that's precisely what I needed' - I think adding a time delay rule would more likely lead to less accepted answers because a one-time querent has all they need and if they can't mark it as accepted there and then, they'll go off - write their story and forget about it.

Comment: Note the proposal is not about adding a strict rule, just adding in a suggestion where the querent "should" wait a bit.

Comment: @Tortliena - It's the libertarian in me - but I see Suggestions as merely a step on the road to rules.

Comment: It's perfectly fine for a querent to see in the very first response she gets the perfect answer! But let's not lose sight of the fact that the green checkmark serves other purposes. As a potential respondent, one of the first things its presence tells me is "okay, you don't need to waste your time here --- they've got what they came for." But we're not here to solely and simply help the querent. Our answers have impact on other users. When the querent awards the green checkmark 14 seconds after the first answer comes in, she is actually harming the community by depriving it of other answers.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. What's wrong with having a formal way of stating, "we suggest that..."? It may be true that the OP believes one of the answers provided in the first hour was great... but human nature is to stop providing answers once that green checkmark appears. That means that checking early isn't just a disservice to the OP, it's a disservice to everyone who might later find the question useful. That check mark is NOT all about the OP. One of Stack Exchange's primary purposes is to help the future, not just the present.

Comment: @JBH - maybe for you - I've never let a greentick stop me from giving an answer, especially if I think it's an interesting question.

Comment: @TheDemonLord Examine the difference between answers to questions closed quickly and answers to questions closed more slowly. This is one of those cases where statistics outweigh individual preferences. A big chunk of our users are people who browse [unanswered questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) rather than [newest](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Newest). It may not mean much to you - but quick check marks are a detriment to the value of the site.